# Error in as.data.frame.default: cannot coerce class "c("reactiveExpr", "reactive")" to a data.frame

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple Shiny app that is giving throwing `Error:cannot coerce class "c("reactiveExpr", "reactive")" to a data.frame`. I am trying to subset a data.frame named `positions` by `positions$LineCode` based on user selected `line`. Below is my code.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

lines <- c('All','RD','YL','GR','BL','OR','SV')

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="Metro Positions"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      selectInput('line', 'Select Line:', lines)
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tableOutput('positionstable')
  )
)

positions <- read.csv('positions.csv')

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  pos <- reactive({
    if(input$line!='All'){
      pos <- positions[positions$LineCode==input$line,]
    }
    return(pos)
  })

  output$positionstable <- renderTable(pos())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Should that be `input$lines`?

Comment: No, the name of `selectInput` is 'line'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that your reactive does not know what `pos` variable is in case that `if` statement is not executed, that is in case `input$line == 'All'`. Then you are asking it to return variable unknown in the context.

Comment: Thanks, changing the `if` statement to the code below fixes it:
`if(input$line!='All'){
      pos <- positions[positions$LineCode==input$line,]
} else {
      pos <- positions
}
`